# Ardulink 2 unable to receive message from analog Pin1 using Serial.print

Tags: arduino-uno, ardulink

I have started ardulink mqtt to listen to analog pin 1 of the arduino uno
as follow running on windows 10 with mosquitto mqtt broker 1.5.8
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java  -jar ardulink-mqtt-2.1.0.jar -a 1 -connection "ardulink://serial-jssc?port=COM3&pingprobe=false" -standalone

However I could not get any response despite subscribe the topics with home/devices/ardulink/A1/value/get ?

I do not see any publishing being log from the ardulink log or mosquitto

From the Arduino serial monitor , I did  see all the output from Serial.print indicating the sketch was in fact fully uploaded to the Arduino uno.

arduino code

```
int sensorValue;
// variable to calibrate low value
int sensorLow = 1023;
// variable to calibrate high value
int sensorHigh = 0;



void setup() {

 Serial.begin(115200);

  // calibrate for the first five seconds after program runs
  while (millis() < 5000) {
    // record the maximum sensor value
    sensorValue = analogRead(A1);
    if (sensorValue > sensorHigh) {
      sensorHigh = sensorValue;
    }
    // record the minimum sensor value
    if (sensorValue < sensorLow) {
      sensorLow = sensorValue;
    }
  }

}

void loop() {
  //read the input from A1 and store it in a variable
  sensorValue = analogRead(A1);


Serial.print(sensorValue);
  // wait for a moment
  delay(1000);
}
```

Ardulink Mqtt log

```
C:\ardulink\lib>C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java -jar ardulink-mqtt-2.1.0.jar -a 1 -d 13 -connection "ardulink://serial-jss
c?port=COM4&pingprobe=false" -clientId ardulink
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/ardulink/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/ardulink/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:04 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext start
INFO: Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:04 PM org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy doStart
INFO: JMX is enabled
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:04 PM org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter doStart
INFO: Loaded 182 type converters
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:04 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry doStart
INFO: Runtime endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage statistics of all incoming and outgoing endpoints (c
ache limit: 1000)
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:14 PM org.ardulink.core.ConnectionBasedLink startListening
INFO: Starting listening on pin ANALOG 1
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:14 PM org.ardulink.core.ConnectionBasedLink startListening
INFO: Starting listening on pin DIGITAL 13
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:14 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent preProcessUri
WARNING: Supplied URI 'mqtt:mqttMain?host=tcp://localhost:1883&subscribeTopicNames=home/devices/ardulink/#&connectAttemp
tsMax=1&reconnectAttemptsMax=0' contains unsafe characters, please check encoding
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext doStartCamel
INFO: AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn
this option off as it may improve performance.
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext doStartCamel
INFO: StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at h
ttp://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor doStart
INFO: Defaulting to MemoryAggregationRepository
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor doStart
INFO: Using CompletionInterval to run every 250 millis.
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.component.mqtt.MQTTEndpoint connect
INFO: Connecting to tcp://localhost:1883 using 10 seconds timeout
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.component.mqtt.MQTTEndpoint$2 onConnected
INFO: MQTT Connection connected to tcp://localhost:1883
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers
INFO: Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[ardulink://serial-jssc?listenTo=A1%2CD13&pingprobe=false&port=C
OM4]
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers
INFO: Route: route2 started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://endOfAnalogAggregation]
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers
INFO: Route: route3 started and consuming from: Endpoint[mqtt:mqttMain?host=tcp://localhost:1883&subscribeTopicNames=hom
e/devices/ardulink/#&connectAttemptsMax=1&reconnectAttemptsMax=0]
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext start
INFO: Total 3 routes, of which 3 are started.
Apr 01, 2019 2:44:15 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext start
INFO: Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 10.898 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue after including the standard ardulink protocol , below is the revised arduino code .

```
int sensorValue;
// variable to calibrate low value
int sensorLow = 1023;
// variable to calibrate high value
int sensorHigh = 0;
// LED pin
const int ledPin = 13;
String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data (this is general code you can reuse)
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete (this is general code you can reuse)
void setup() {
  // Make the LED pin an output and turn it on
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("alp://rply/");
  Serial.print("ok?id=0");
  Serial.print('\n'); // End of Message
  Serial.flush();

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

  // calibrate for the first five seconds after program runs

  while (millis() < 5000) {
    // record the maximum sensor value
    sensorValue = analogRead(A1);
    if (sensorValue > sensorHigh) {
      sensorHigh = sensorValue;
    }
  // record the minimum sensor value
    if (sensorValue < sensorLow) {
      sensorLow = sensorValue;
    }
  }


  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  //read the input from A1 and store it in a variable
  serialEvent();
  sensorValue = analogRead(A1);



  if (stringComplete==true){

   if(inputString.startsWith("alp://")) {
         boolean msgRecognized = true;
         if (inputString.substring(6,10)=="ared"){
                //Serial.println(sensorValue);
                digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

         }else{

           msgRecognized = false; 
         }

 // Prepare reply message if caller supply a message id (this is general code you can reuse)
      int idPosition = inputString.indexOf("?id=");
      if(idPosition != -1) {
        String id = inputString.substring(idPosition + 4);
        // print the reply
        Serial.print("alp://rply/");
        if(msgRecognized) { // this sketch doesn't know other messages in this case command is ko (not ok)
          Serial.print("ok?id=");
        } else {
          Serial.print("ko?id=");
        }
        Serial.print(id);
        Serial.print('\n'); // End of Message
        Serial.flush();

      }




  }
// clear the string:
   inputString = "";
   stringComplete = false;
  }

if (sensorValue>0){

        Serial.print("alp://ared/");
        Serial.print("1");
        Serial.print("/");
        Serial.print(sensorValue);
        Serial.print('\n'); // End of Message
        Serial.flush();


}



   delay(1000);








}



void serialEvent() {


  while (Serial.available()>0&&!stringComplete==true) {

    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;

    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not flash Ardulink sketch to the Arduino but something self-written (which does not send any message via the serial link). After flashing Ardulink sketch and starting java mqtt client again everything should work.

Comment: I do not quite comprehend by your 'did not flash Ardulink sketch to the Arduino' statement , I am certain that the sketch  was fully uploaded to the Arduino  before I started the mqtt

Comment: I have added the mqtt log showing mqtt are in fact trigger to  listen on pin A1 and digital pin 13